# An assembly code used array

Tags: assembly, systems-programming

```
int A[R][S][T];

int A[R][S][T];
int store_ele(int i, int j, int k, int *dest) {
    *dest = A[i][j][k];
    return sizeof(A);
}
```

Gcc generates the following assembly code :

```
1.  movl 8(%ebp), %ecx
2.  movl 12(%ebp), %eax
3.  leal (%eax, %eax, 8), %eax
4.  movl %ecx, %edx
5.  sall $6, %edx
6.  sub1 %ecx, %edx
7.  addl %edx, %eax
8.  addl 16(%ebp), %eax
9.  movl A(,%eax,4), %edx
10. movl 20(%ebp), %eax
11. movl %edx, (%eax)
12. movl $2772, %eax
```

Questions : https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ba1Z2.jpg

I don't understand line 9 in assembly code above and these questions.

Comment: oops i made a mistake.. and just edited : ) it's not #define, but just int A[R][S][T]

Answer (score 1):

It's easiest to explain what is going on, by looking at the code one line at a time.

```
1.  movl 8(%ebp), %ecx
```

This loads ecx with the parameter at ebp+8, which is `i`.

```
2.  movl 12(%ebp), %eax
```

This loads eax with the parameter at ebp+12, which is `j`.

```
3.  leal (%eax, %eax, 8), %eax
```

This sets eax to eax+eax*8, basically multiplying itself by 9. So eax is now `j*9`.

```
4.  movl %ecx, %edx
```

This sets edx to ecx which is `i`.

```
5.  sall $6, %edx
```

And this shifts it left 6 bits, multiplying it by 64, so edx is now `i*64`.

```
6.  sub1 %ecx, %edx
```

But now we subtract ecx (which is `i`) from that value, so edx becomes `i*63`.

```
7.  addl %edx, %eax
```

This add edx (`i*63`) to eax (`j*9`), so eax is now `i*63 + j*9`.

```
8.  addl 16(%ebp), %eax
```

And this add the parameter at ebp+16 which is `k`, so eax is now `i*63 + j*9 + k`.

```
9.  movl A(,%eax,4), %edx
```

This is accessing the `A` array with the offset eax*4 and storing it in edx.

Since eax is `i*63 + j*9 + k`, you can think of this as accessing a single dimenson int array at offset `i*63 + j*9 + k`. We multiply by 4 because that's the size of an int.

Note that you can rewrite that index expression as `i*7*9 + j*9 + k`. From that, I hope you can start to see how the various dimensions of the array are being accessed.

```
10. movl 20(%ebp), %eax
```

This load eax with the parameter at ebp+20, which is `dest`.

```
11. movl %edx, (%eax)
```

And this stores edx, what we just got from our array, at the address in eax (`dest`). It's effectively doing `*dest = A[i*7*9 + j*9 + k]` if `A` were a single dimension int array;

```
12. movl $2772, %eax
```

This is just returning the value 2772, the size of `A`.

Since you now know the size of `A`, if you look back at how `i`, `j` and `k` have been multiplied when dereferencing the array, I'm hoping it should be fairly easy for you to figure out the values for `R`, `S` and `T`.

**UPDATE: calculating the dimensions**

If the dimensions of your array are `R`, `S` and `T`, then to access an element at `i`,`j`,`k`, what is the formula you would use?

Think of the array as a big three dimensional block with dimensions `R x S x T`. The `i` index selects a two dimensional slice from that block with dimensions `S x T`. The `j` index selects a row from that slice of length `T`. And the `k` index is just the `k`th item in that row.

So the one dimensional address can be represented as `i*S*T + j*T + k`. Now if you look back at the array calculations in the disassembly above, do you not notice that same pattern? Can you see which values in the disassembly map to `S` and `T`?

As for finding `R`: you know that the number of items in the array is 693 (the 2772 byte size divided by the int size of 4); and you also know that the number of items can be calculated with `R*S*T` (think of the three dimensional block again). Therefore `R*S*T = 693` and you know `S` and `T`, so finding `R` is just a matter of division.

Comment: thank u! it's very kind answer and easy to understand it for me.. but I still cant understand question A... Extend equation 3.1 from tow dimenstion to three to provide a formula for thelocation fo array element A[i][j][k]

Comment: It's hard to answer that without knowing what equation 3.1 is.

Comment: I got the size of A is 693 (cuz integer is 4) and how can I get the i, j, k(R,T,S) even I don't know the start address?

Comment: I've added an explanation to my answer. I hope that's clear enough for you to work out the rest.